# Change logo when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the logo of my sticky header when the page scroll arrives on a div with a dark class. I managed to change my logo when switching to the first div but as soon as there is another one it doesn't work. I want to switch logo by default when it is a "light" class.

Code HTML

```
<header id="masthead"><img src="my_logo.png" /></header>
<div class="dark"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="dark"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
```

jquery with an each loop on the element. Several variables with element detection via position().top

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var defaultLogo = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS5CeIvMpSmDtVz1UzMKmQojMj-fc3N1qlbvHrlzV6Ozw&s"; // Default logo
  var darkLogo = "https://freesvg.org/img/Logo-Logo-White-with-Black-Background.png"; // Logo for dark background

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var currentSection = null;

    $('div').each(function() {
      var top = $(this).offset().top - 100; // Adjust based on your header size
      var bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

      if (scrollPos >= top && scrollPos <= bottom) {
        currentSection = $(this);
        return false; // Break the loop
      }
    });

    if (currentSection) {
      if (currentSection.hasClass('dark')) {
        $('#masthead img').attr('src', darkLogo);
      } else {
        $('#masthead img').attr('src', defaultLogo);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

.title {
  color: #5C6AC4;
}

.dark,
.light {
  height: 600px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
}

.dark {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.light {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#masthead {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello, World!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="masthead"><img src="https://freesvg.org/img/Logo-Logo-White-with-Black-Background.png" /></header>
  <div class="dark"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="dark"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This code listens for the scroll event, iterates through each div to determine which one is at the top of the viewport, and changes the logo based on whether the div has a dark or light class.